# How to add horizontal lines on bar charts d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a bar chart in the link below http://jsbin.com/cunecazene/edit?html,output
The bar chart is generated by type and count in the array.

```
 var data = [
   { type: 'type 1', count: 10, comp: 12}, 
   { type: 'type 2', count: 20, comp: 22},
   { type: 'type 3', count: 30, comp: 37},
   { type: 'type 4', count: 35, comp: 31}
  ];
```

I want to know if there is any way that I can add lines on the bar chart like the example in the picture using the "comp" in the array. 
Appreciate your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives:

- `d3.select` some `<line>` elements, bind data to them, `.enter`, and render them using your `xScale` and `yScale`, all very similarly to what you've done with `<rect>`s so far.

  Remember to [put the two in different layer groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879547/with-d3-how-can-i-avoid-svg-graph-links-being-rendered-over-nodes/33884426#33884426) so the lines always appear over the rectangles.
- On `.enter`, append an [SVG group element (`<g>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) and append the `<rect>` and `<line>` to *that*, then on update, position it with a single operation.

  This takes some more thinking to get right, but keeps the document tree clearer and is more performant due to requiring less data binding and DOM operations.